# Помогите разобраться со словарями в Python

Tags: python, dict

помогите с задачей на словари :
Дан текст, состоящий из количества строк текста и самого текста. Вывести на
экран построчно каждое слово и сколько раз оно встречается в тексте. Для
реализации используйте словари.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ну алгоритм простой

1. вы разбиваете текст на слова через `split()`
2. дальше вы проверяете, есть ли данное слово в словаре в качестве ключа и если нет - добавляете слово со значением 0
3. прибавляете на 1 значение по ключу в качестве которого используете ваше слово

проще всего сделать так:

```
words = dict()

...

words[word] = word.get(word, 0) + 1
```

`word.get(word, 0)` пытается извлечь значение по ключу `word` и если такого ключа в словаре нет, то возвращает 0